# Recursive directory search including files inside ZIP's and RAR's

Tags: javascript, node.js

i'm trying to find a solution for my problem. I need get all files inside a target directory, including files inside zip and rars. Is this possible? Currently i'm working with this version, that takes all files inside all directories, including zips and rars files, but not what is inside.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var walk = function(dir, done) {
  var results = [];
  fs.readdir(dir, function(err, list) {
    if (err) return done(err);
    var pending = list.length;
    if (!pending) return done(null, results);
    list.forEach(function(file) {
      file = path.resolve(dir, file);
      fs.stat(file, function(err, stat) {
        if (stat && stat.isDirectory()) {
          walk(file, function(err, res) {
            results = results.concat(res);
            if (!--pending) done(null, results);
          });
        } else {
          results.push(file);
          if (!--pending) done(null, results);
        }
      });
    });
  });
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

While recursively looking for file,if you get a zip file you can use module like [adm-zip](https://github.com/cthackers/adm-zip) to getEntries of zip file and do the recursive search again.

Answer (score 0):

You may look into some external library:

Like jszip: https://stuk.github.io/jszip/

Install via npm and when you're looking for file, if you get a .zip or .rar file you can use jszip to get the list of files inside of the .zip or .rar folder